# Fix the integrity error while using Python with sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x

[Integrity Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okKKb.png)

I am trying to join 2 tables, Employee and Employee Task on Employee_id but getting Integrity Error. I was able to join Employee and Department on Department_id.

Employee:

- Employee_fname,
- Employee_lname,
- Employee_title,
- Department_id,
- Employee_id

EmployeeTask:

- Project_id_no,
- Employee_id,
- Employee_task_in_project

Department:

- Department_id,
- Department_name,
- Department_location,
- Department_phone_ext

I am using following statement to join. What's is the issue?

```
sql = f"SELECT Employee_id, Employee_fname, Employee_lname, Employee_title,Employee_task_in_project FROM Employee FULL JOIN EmployeeTask ON Employee.Employee_id = EmployeeTask.Employee_id WHERE Employee.Employee_id = \'{str(employeeno)}\'"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT Employee_id, Employee_fname, Employee_lname, Employee_title,Employee_task_in_project
FROM Employee FULL JOIN
     EmployeeTask
     ON Employee.Employee_id = EmployeeTask.Employee_id
WHERE Employee.Employee_id = ?
```

At least one problem is that `Employee_id` is in both tables, but the reference in the `SELECT` doesn't specify which one.  This generates an ambiguous reference error.

I would suggest writing the query as:

```
SELECT e.Employee_id, e.Employee_fname, e.Employee_lname, 
       e.Employee_title, et.Employee_task_in_project
FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN
     EmployeeTask et
     ON e.Employee_id = et.Employee_id
WHERE e.Employee_id = ?;
```

Notes:

- Quality *all* column references, so it is clear to you, other people, and the compiler which table they come from.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- `FULL JOIN` is almost never necessary.  In this case, a `LEFT JOIN` seems correct -- it keeps all employees even those with no tasks.
- Learn to use parameters instead of munging query strings.